# Selecting same column multiple times for different criterias - SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to run a query which selects two same columns but with different condition/criteria. I am able to run that query independently and get a result but when i try to run them together ( as shown in the second part ) i get an error. The expected table is shown below as save_line1, save_line2. But the output i get is the first row - for all the rows.

I would like to know what changes to be made to my second query to make it work. Thanks.

```
select save_line from save_output_table  
where execution_id in ('292') 
and seq_id = '0' 
and save_type='R' 
order by line_id ASC

+------------+
| Save_line  |
+------------+
|         17 |
|         22 |
|         23 |
+------------+



SELECT 
( select save_line 
 from save_output_table
 where execution_id in ('292') 
 and seq_id = '0' 
and save_type='R' 
order by line_id ASC 
) as save_line1,
( select save_line 
  from save_output_table  
 where execution_id in ('286') 
and seq_id = '0' 
and save_type='R' 
order by line_id ASC 
 ) as save_line2
 from save_output_table 

 +-------------+------------+
 | Save_line 1 | Save_line2 |
 +-------------+------------+
 |          17 |          9 |
 |          22 |          5 |
 |          23 |          3 |
 +-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Subqueries in the outer SELECTs column list should return 0 or 1 rows, otherwise an error could appear. Are you sure you're not missing a "AND saveline=s.saveline" in each of your two sub-selects? For this to work you also need a " s" at the very end of your query. And why the order by's?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT stragg( distinct(save_line1.save_line)), stragg( distinct(save_line2.save_line))
from
( select save_line 
 from save_output_table 
 where execution_id in ('292') 
 and seq_id = '0' 
and save_type='R' 
order by line_id ASC 
) as save_line1,
( select save_line 
  from save_output_table  
 where execution_id in ('286') 
and seq_id = '0' 
and save_type='R' 
order by line_id ASC 
 ) as save_line2
```

Comment: I dont want to get a null or like a case. I need two independent results as two columns with the criteria mentioned

Comment: its giving me incorrect results.

Comment: Are the results in the wrong order?

Comment: for every row in the left column(save_line1) - i get all the rows in save_line2

Comment: stragg will get all the values for each column, but I'm not sure how to turn that into a column again.